# From two data lists, how can I identify all distinct combinations and count the number of each combination

Tags: excel

I have two lists of data in Excel:

```
MET TYR
MET ASN
MET TYR
MET ASN
MET TYR
MET ASN
MET TYR
ARG ASN
ARG TYR
ARG ASN
ARG TYR
ARG ASN
ARG TYR
ARG ASN
ARG TYR
HIS ASN
HIS TYR
HIS ASN
LYS ASP
LYS LEU
LYS ASP
LYS LEU
LYS ASP
LYS LEU
ASN ASN
ARG SER
LYS ASP
ILE GLU
THR TYR
```

I am trying to identify all the distinct combinations, for example, MET-TYR, MET-ASN, ARG-ASN, ARG-TYR, HIS-ASN, and so on. 
I also want to tell the number of times each combination appears. In this case, as you read through the entire list, MET-TYR appears 4 times, MET-ASN appears 3 times, ARG-ASN appears 4 times, etc.

What I have tried is combining the data into one column (so "MET TYR" appears in one cell instead of two), and then using the excel formula =SUM(IF(S4:S32="MET TYR",1,0)). However I still have to type it in manually for every combination, which takes a LOT of time, as I have hundreds of such lists, some of which are thousands rows long.

Any idea on how I may possibly arrange the data, use formulas, or use code to make this faster?

Many, many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `countif`?

Comment: You can use Data --> Delete Duplicates to get the unique combinations then use: `COUNTIF(A:A & "-" & B:B,A1 & "-" & B1)`.  But all this can be done in a pivot table Quicker and easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated a pivot table with a helper column will do what you want:

[image]

In C2 I put:

```
=A2&"-"& B2
```

Then copied down.

Then using that column I built the pivot table.

---

If that is not what you want then do this:

Copy and paste the list into columns D and E.  Highlight The go to DATA --> Remove Duplicates.

[image]

Hit OK.

Then in F2 put the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A = D2)*(B:B =E2))
```

Then copy down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your initial data in column **A**
2. Copy column **A** to column **B**
3. Remove duplicates in column **B** using the *Remove Duplicates* feature in the *Data* ribbon tab
4. In cell **C1** enter: `=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)` and copy down:

[image]